# How to send a message from a windows azure server to a client mobile app(iOS) without the client sending any request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am maintaining a queue at the server end to which users can add files. And the queue on the app which shows the files that have been added by different users has to be dynamically updated. I dont want to poll the server periodically to check if there is any new item on the queue. Is there any way to notify the client app that a new item has arrived on the queue and u have to poll the server now to retrieve that file? And I dont want a push notification, as with push notification the user will be notified, i rather want the message to be handled internally and the app should poll the server when the message is received

Please let me know if you have any ideas, i am struck on my project because of this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. Its Web Sockets!! Web Sockets can be used to maintain persistent connections between client and server. And there is a library for that - SignalR

SignalR is a new library which was introduced for ASP.Net developers to build real time web applications where server needs to continuously push data to clients.

Some links for SignalR

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/17/signalr-building-real-time-web-applications.aspx

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/206/SignalR-And-Knockout-In-ASP.NET-Web-Pages-Using-WebMatrix

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are exactly for that, although your app will have to register initially (for security) - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/12/04/ios-support-with-windows-azure-mobile-services-now-with-push-notifications.aspx

Comment: no i dont want to push notify the user that an item is added. Like push notifications would come in the notifications bar of the phone right. I dont want that. I want a message which can be internally handled by the app without the user knowing. Any idea?

Comment: I haven't worked with iOS but I built an application using Windows Azure Mobile Service and Windows 8 (http://gauravmantri.com/2012/08/30/how-i-built-an-awesome-chat-application-for-windows-8-with-windows-azure-mobile-service/). There I implemented push notification but when a notification comes to the device, I handled that event in my code so that the user did not get a toast notification. You may want to look into iOS SDK for Windows Azure Mobile Service (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/tree/master/sdk/iOS) which can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Bitsian,

You can use **Windows Azure Service Bus Notification Hubs**. Its just released few days ago (not even a week). It will support multiplatform push nottification (ios,android,windows 8,win phone now)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj927170.aspx

[Check this link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Subscribe/). It has some great video tutorials to start on

Comment: no i dont want to push notify the user that an item is added. Like push notifications would come in the notifications bar of the phone right. I dont want that. I want a message which can be internally handled by the app without the user knowing. Any idea?

Comment: Then check out mobile services...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/10/17/announcing-the-windows-azure-mobile-services-october-update.aspx
(see this part 'Access to Windows Azure Blob, Table, Queues, and ServiceBus from your Mobile Service')

Comment: ...that would require the device to pull....I don't think you can get data onto iOS (or any device for that matter) not through notifications and not through polling. Windows has the ability for notifications to deliver data to the app rather than a toast, I don't know if iOS has something equivalent